# Nokia Lumia 925 network selection problem

Tags: lumia-925, lumia-denim-update

I updated my Lumia 925 to Denim, but a strange thing happened after the upgrade; I can't select 3G. The drop-down list freezes on 2G. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried getting your network to push the APN settings to your phone?

Answer (score 2):

As [Apoorv](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/12104/apoorv) mentioned you could try and make a reset. But before that you should:

1. Check if there is another update available. Including installing and running [Upgrade Advisor from Store.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/windows-10-mobile-upgrade-advisor)
2. Remember to have backup activated before you do.
3. Take note that there are two kinds of resets that you could do: Hard and Soft (always try soft first). You can read how to do both kinds of resets [here.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/wiki/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d)

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try to reset your phone ! Try to reset it and then see. Sometimes the firmware do creates problem so resetting is the only fix